# Purpose of Object truth check in IF loop (if Object && ...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-statements, operators, fs

I have been trying to wrap my head around a piece of code in a Node.Js tutorial (comments are mine).

```
// All images array
  let allImages = [];    

// Returns array of filenames or objects at given path 'dirPath'
    let files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

// Loops through the array
for (file of files) {
      let fileLocation = path.join(dirPath, file);
// Retrieves information object about each file path
      var stat = fs.statSync(fileLocation);
// Recursively check each subdirectory for image files.
            if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                getImagesFromDir(fileLocation);
// Checks if it is a file, and if the extension is either '.jpeg' or '.png'
// Why is the first condition (if stat) needed ??
            if (stat && stat.isFile() && ['.jpeg', '.png'].indexOf(path.extname(fileLocation)) != -1) {
                allImages.push('images/'+file); 
      }
  }
```

I understand that `fs.statSync` (`stat`) outputs an object. I am therefore wondering:

What is the purpose of the first condition?

```
if ( stat && ...
```

Comment: Seems pointless indeed.